# MySQL not in Where

Tags: mysql

I have a table named as "Project" with project data as follows.

```
+--------+------------+------------+----------+--------+---------------+--------+
| In Num | pro_no_old | pro_no_new | pro_name | amount | budget_status | status |
+--------+------------+------------+----------+--------+---------------+--------+
|      1 | pro1       |            | project1 | 200000 | original      |      1 |
|      2 | pro2       |            | project2 | 150000 | original      |      1 |
|      3 | pro3       |            | project3 | 300000 | original      |      1 |
|      4 | pro2       | pro4       | project4 | 100000 | revised       |      0 |
+--------+------------+------------+----------+--------+---------------+--------+
```

02) The pro_name, "Project4" has become from Project2 by revising. Then I need to get projects without revised projects like Project2. In the other words, no need to get previous project of a revised one. Desired Out put may be as follows.

```
+--------+------------+------------+----------+--------+---------------+--------+
| In Num | pro_no_old | pro_no_new | pro_name | amount | budget_status | status |
+--------+------------+------------+----------+--------+---------------+--------+
|      1 | pro1       |            | project1 | 200000 | original      |      1 |
|      3 | pro3       |            | project3 | 300000 | original      |      1 |
|      4 | pro2       | pro4       | project4 | 100000 | revised       |      0 |
+--------+------------+------------+----------+--------+---------------+--------+
```

03) I used the following query to get the desired output.

```
SELECT * FROM project WHERE('pro_no_old in (SELECT  pro_no_old FROM project where budget_status = "original"))
```

04) But didn't get the expected result. Can anyone help me ?

## Desired output after Editing

```
+--------+------------+------------+----------+--------+---------------+--------+
| In Num | pro_no_old | pro_no_new | pro_name | amount | budget_status | status |
+--------+------------+------------+----------+--------+---------------+--------+
|      1 | pro1       |            | project1 | 200000 | original      |      1 |
|      3 | pro3       |            | project3 | 300000 | original      |      1 |
|      5 | pro4       | pro5       | project5 |  50000 | revised       |      0 |
+--------+------------+------------+----------+--------+---------------+--------+
```

Comment: Have you made an attempt? What did you come up with? What was the problem with it?

Comment: @ Lightness Races in Orbit. See after edit

Comment: I'm curious - what happens if the budget is revised again?

Comment: @ P.Salmon. If change the budget of a project (Like Project2 from 150000 to 100000) a new project no will assign to a new one.This revision can be changed more & more as per need

Comment: You say you didn't get the expected result. What result did you get? What did you try next?

Comment: @ Lightness Races in Orbit. I need to get the output as mentioned under 02 (As per the second table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about your data model but if you are only interested in the last entry for pro_no_old

```
select * 
from t
where innum = (select max(innum) from t t1 where t1.pro_no_old = t.pro_no_old); 

+-------+------------+------------+----------+--------+---------------+--------+
| InNum | pro_no_old | pro_no_new | pro_name | amount | budget_status | status |
+-------+------------+------------+----------+--------+---------------+--------+
|     1 | pro1       | NULL       | project1 | 200000 | original      |      1 |
|     3 | pro3       | NULL       | project3 | 300000 | original      |      1 |
|     4 | pro2       | pro4       | project4 | 100000 | revised       |      0 |
+-------+------------+------------+----------+--------+---------------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: If I need to revise project4 to project5 with the amount 50000, what can be changed in the query. Pls. see my Editing on the original question